# Python - How to fix table row height and increase the size of the table based on the number of lines using PLT.TABLE?

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing

I need to plot a table beside a graph, and the number of lines it is not fixed, I mean, sometimes I will have 2 lines and sometimes I will have 5 or more lines. 
Saying that, I need to plot a table that "fits" the number of lines for each situation. 
My question is: How to fix table row height and also increase the size of the table based on the number of lines? i.e for each new row, the height of the table increases.
Follow to image that
[FFT with one peak - table with 2 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQRbO.png)
[FFT with four peaks - table with 5 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCOrf.png)
Follow my code below:

```
    import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import peakutils

a =0.5
#a =input("entre com o limite: ")

# Number of samplepoints
N = 600
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 800.0
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y1 = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)+ 0.7*np.sin(30.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)+ 0.5*np.sin(10.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
#yf1 = scipy.fftpack.fft(y1)
yf1 = np.fft.fft(y1)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N/2)

v1 = 2.0/N * np.abs(yf1[:N//2])

# Find peaks
indexes = peakutils.indexes(v1, thres = a , min_dist=1,thres_abs= True)

columns = ('Freq (Hz)','Amplitude')
table_vals = np.column_stack((xf[indexes],v1[indexes]))
table_vals = np.around(table_vals,decimals=2)
print table_vals


plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(xf,v1)
plt.scatter(xf[indexes],v1[indexes],color ='r')
plt.table(cellText= table_vals, colLabels=columns, rowLoc = 'right',colLoc='right',
                      colWidths = [0.3,0.3],bbox=[1.05,0.5,0.5,0.5],cellLoc = 'right')
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.65)
#plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
plt.xlabel('Freq(Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The last number in `bbox` (`0.5` here) is the height of the table. You can make this proportional to the number of rows. In the simplest case e.g. `0.1*table_vals.shape[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Do you know how can I make the table to be aligned with the graph? I mean, depending on the number of rows the table goes  up or down...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Your suggestion worked pretty well...I am not having problems anymore with the size of the table and rows. Now I am having problem with the location of the table, I mean, depending on how many rows the table has, the position of the table changes from one case to another....when I have more rows (i.e 6 rows or more), I cannot see the first rows of the table.

Comment: I guess you mean the inverse? Namely that the position stays the same, but you want it to change? E.g. you could set it such that the y value is 1-tableheight to have it look like it's anchored on top.

Comment: Exactly.
Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: As said, if the height of the table is e.g. `0.1*table_vals.shape[0]` then the position of the table may be set to `1.0 - 0.1*table_vals.shape[0]`.